# Set up a Node.JS application on cloud server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, domain-name-system, node.js

I have full access to a cloud server (running Ubuntu 14.04) via SSH.

I already have installed Node.JS from PPA:

```
sudo apt-get install -y python-software-properties python g++ make
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs -y
```

Now, I want to set up my first Node.JS application on my cloud server. It will send a `Hello World` message from server to client.

```
require("http").createServer(function (req, res) {
   res.end("Hello World!");
}).listen(3000);
```

Then:

```
$ node my-script.js
```

What are the steps to allow users to see this hello world message at a custom domain (e.g. `example.com`)?

Comment: What do you mean, "send it to a custom domain"?  Do you mean that when a user asks for `http://example.com:3000` they'll see your message?

Comment: @AndrewSchulman When somebody will open in browser `production.example.com` will get `Hello World!` response.

Comment: OK, then why is your server listening on port 3000?  Don't you want 80?

Comment: @AndrewSchulman Probably. It's the first time when I set up NodeJS on a cloud server. I am getting `EACCES` error for `listen(80)`.

Comment: If I start the process with `sudo`, then it works fine! But, how can I avoid running the process with `sudo`?

Comment: OK, I understand. EACCES is expected if you're not running as root.  So you can either use port 80 and run `sudo node myscript.js`, or expect users to ask for `production.example.com:3000`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14976/discussion-between-ionica-bizau-and-andrew-schulman).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

1. Linked my domain with the server ip adding `A` record in DNS management:

   ```
   Sr No  | Name                   | Destination IP Address | Status    
   ------------------------------------------------------------------
   ...
   3      | production.example.com | xxx.xxx.xx.xxx         | Active
   ```

   Where *Destination IP Address* is the ip address used when connecting via `ssh`:

   ```
   $ ssh ubuntu@xxx.xxx.xx.xxx -A
   ```
2. [Redirect `80` port to `3000`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18949557/1420197)

   > `$ sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000`
3. Created a script named `index.js` containing:

   ```
   require("http").createServer(function (req, res) {
      console.log(req.url);
      res.end("Hello World!");
   }).listen(3000);
   ```
4. Run it using:

   > `$ node index.js`

Then, the response of `production.example.com` is `Hello World!`.